# Use Apostrophes in search query in datatable result to filter data

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am getting data in one data collection. Now I want to filter it out based on designername value.

But problem is that in designername value I am getting apostrophes so because of that it is breaking and not returning data.

Value I am getting in desginername column is this :

```
Men's Jewelry
```

Here if you see in Men there is apostrophes and because of that I am not getting result.

Using below line I am trying to get filtered data.

```
DataRow[] dr = dtCollections2.Select("designername = '" + strDesigner + "'");
```

Error I am getting is this :

```
{"Message":"Syntax error: Missing operand after \u0027s\u0027 operator.","StackTrace":"   at System.Data.ExpressionParser.Parse()\r\n   at System.Data.DataExpression..ctor(DataTable table, String expression, Type type)\r\n   at System.Data.Select..ctor(DataTable table, String filterExpression, String sort, DataViewRowState recordStates)\r\n   at System.Data.DataTable.Select(String filterExpression)\r\n at "ExceptionType":"System.Data.SyntaxErrorException"})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.select?view=net-7.0) for the Select method refers to [this page](https://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/) for examples of the query syntax, from which we can see that single-quote characters should be escaped by using two of them in a row.

> String values are enclosed within single quotes `' '`. If the string contains single quote `'`, the quote must be doubled.
>
> ```
> [C#]
> dataView.RowFilter = "Name = 'John'"        // string value
> dataView.RowFilter = "Name = 'John ''A'''"  // string with single quotes "John 'A'"
>
> dataView.RowFilter = String.Format("Name = '{0}'", "John 'A'".Replace("'", "''"));
> ```

So in your case:

```
DataRow[] dr = dtCollections2.Select("designername = '" + strDesigner.Replace("'", "''") + "'")
```